# R: ggplot2: Legend overlaps different point shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2

as you can see, the legend overlaps different point shapes in following plot

```
europe <- c(70, 67, 56, 66, 80, 75, 81, 55)
data <- data.frame(europe)

ggplot(data, aes(x=4, y=europe)) +
  labs(x = "Europe", y = NULL, title = NULL) +  
  geom_errorbar(y=data$europe, ymin=min(data$europe), ymax=max(data$europe), size=1.5, width=1, color="#7F7F7F") +
  geom_point(aes(x=4, y=data$europe[1], color="today"), size=18, shape=18) +
  geom_point(aes(x=4, y=data$europe[6], color="last week"), size=16) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(50, 85), expand = c(0, 0), breaks=seq(0, 1000, 5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 8), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = element_blank(),
                 labels = c("today", "last week"),
                 values = c("#A50021", "#00669C"))
```

[image]

so I have been unsuccessfully trying to fix the overlap such as by adding

```
+ scale_shape_manual(name = element_blank(),
                 labels = c("today", "last week"),
                 values = c(18, 16))
```

what does not change anything. my ideal would be, of course, one red circle and one blue square. can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things very difficult for yourself by adding things to the legend that are not in the data, because generally legends work best when they are mapped to the data using the aes. That's the ease of ggplot: get everything in your dataframe, set aes and if you want to you can change the defaults by using `scale_...._manual.`

I have added a 'weekday' variable to your data, to be able to use the aes correctly.

```
#add weekday variable
data$weekday <- c("today","last week")

ggplot(data, aes(x=4, y=europe)) +
  labs(x = "Europe", y = NULL, title = NULL) +  
  geom_errorbar(aes(y=europe, ymin=min(europe), ymax=max(europe)), size=1.5, width=1, color="#7F7F7F") +
  #add subset of data here. Not that x and y were already mapped, and color, shape and size are mapped 
  #INSIDE aes
  geom_point(data=data[c(1,6),], aes(color=weekday, shape=weekday, size=weekday))+
  #manual scales
  scale_color_manual(values = c("today"="#A50021", "last week"="#00669C")) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c("today"=18, "last week"=16)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("today"=20,"last week"=18))
```

[image]

Edit with removing the errorbar:

```
#do some reshaping/manipulating into a dataframe for plotting

plotdata <- data.frame(value=europe[c(1,6)],
                       weekday=c("today","last week"),
                       limit_value=c(min(europe),max(europe)),
                       limit_label=c("min","max"))

p2 <- ggplot(plotdata) +
  geom_point(aes(x=4,y=value,shape=weekday,colour=weekday, size=weekday))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("today"="#A50021",
                              "last week"="#00669C"))+
  scale_size_manual(values=c("today"=18,"last week"=16))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("today"=18, "last week"=20))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=limit_value),colour="grey",size=2)
p2
```

[image]

Or, because time-intervals can also be important you can do this. It makes the time-relations clearer. In my opinion, min and max are clear by themselves. If not, you can always add a text label (or make the lines red and blue or something).
[image]

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly you're trying to plot, with all the manual groupings. I think I messed up some of the color/shape/value mappings in my example and can't get them properly. (Pointed out to me by @Jaap.  You can look into `stat_summary`, but realize that you now have a plot with two points and one errorbar. How should it be interpreted?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks for your help! Actually, I am not plotting real errors, but simply a data range. I get one new data point each day. So what I am doing is plotting the value of today, and the value of one week ago. The error bar shows the minimum and the maximum of the whole data that is collected over time. Your note about what I am trying to plot brings me to another question: is ist possible to add a grey line in the legend, that has the label "min/max"? This would probably make the plot more understandable.

Comment: If that's the case, I would personally opt for just horizontal bars. The shape you've currently chosen is very often used as an errorbar/indicating a confidence interval. I don't think I'm the only one confused. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I totally agree with your solution! The thing is, that I can't really modify the plot, since I have the task to reproduce my company's graphs, which are made in excel, identically(!) with R. For the min/max, I was trying to add another geom_line with, let's say, y=0, make it grey and give it the label "min/max". That didn't work either: I surprisingly got 5 labels in the legend: 2 for the point, hovewver in black, and 3 for the lines (blue, red and grey). @Heroka