# R ggplot Legend shows shapes inccorectly

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a reason why ggplot might mess with the geom_point shape in the legend?

In the actual plot everything looks with the shapes correctly plotted as circles, but in the legend it shows them as weird boxes / squares, i.e. it is showing this:
[image]

But it should show this:

[image]

Could it be because I have an `ifelse` in my `geom_point` ? This is what I have here for this part:
`geom_point(aes( y=y, colour=ifelse( (ty>308)&(Time < chron(times=c('08:30:30.0'))), ifelse(side=='left', 'red', 'blue'),'gray')), na.rm = T)`

Comment: Could you share a reproducible example of your dataset?

Comment: How do you add the legend. I think that has something to do with that.

Comment: @Masoud The legend is automatic here, I did not have to explicitly create it.

Comment: OK. Include your code and a sample dataset. Please read [How to make a great reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Masoud I don't get why in R stackoverflow questions, datasets are necessary when in other languages it isn't (e.g. Python). I'm new to R so please feel me in if I am missing something. It seems like no one really knows what's going on until they play around with it themselves.

Comment: @tbone different classes of data have different behaviors. Sometimes (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701207/column-labels-cropped-when-using-pheatmap)) a text would be treated as integer and it would mess up the plot. This user had not provided a reproducible example but gratefully he found a solution by himself. There are numerous other reasons like easier and more precise reproduction of the error. Addressing the exact problem versus providing a general approach that may or may not resolve OP's problem, etc. Cheers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646886/r-ggplot2-legend-overlaps-different-point-shapes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is actually because `geom_point` and `geom_line` are both plotted and the points are varying according to the `size` parameter. ggplot is trying to show a point on a line which looks good when it is small and clear but becomes strange and box-like as the size varies.

To make it clearer, turning off the legend for either the line or the points will keep just one.

For example:
`geom_line(aes(y=foo , colour='green'), show.legend = F)`